# Keep running code even if a nullException is found

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, exception, null

I'm running a code where I'm reading an XML file and saving it in local variables using vb.net.

Sadly, not all of the XML are equally structure so I'm comming into the problem that if one field of those that I'm trying to map is missing it will stop running the code and prompt the error.

I would like, if a field is not fund, keep it as null and runs the code until the end.

I tried using try and catch with no luck.

```
Var1 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test1").InnerText
Var2 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test2").Value
Var3 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test3").InnerText
```

Now, if Var2 is missing on one of the xml's it will stop running the code and not take the Var3 even if present.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you split the statement into `Node2 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test2")` and then check for Null before doing `Var2 = Node2.Value` ?

Comment: Interesting wil take a look thanks but then it would crash on the line Node2 I beleive and make the code much messier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 you can use the null propagating operator `?`

```
Var1 = xmlNode?.SelectSingleNode("Test1")?.InnerText
Var2 = xmlNode?.SelectSingleNode("Test2")?.Value
Var3 = xmlNode?.SelectSingleNode("Test3")?.InnerText
```

If you are using something older then you will have to do this long hand:

```
If xmlNode IsNot Nothing Then 
    Dim node = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test1")
    If node IsNot Nothing then Var1 = node.InnerText
    node = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test2")
    If node IsNot Nothing then Var1 = node.Value
    'etc.
End If
```

Note that you can do this using a `Try...Catch` but this would be ugly code:

```
Try
    Var1 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test1").InnerText
Catch ex As Exception
     'ignore
End Try
Try
    Var2 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test2").Value
Catch ex As Exception
     'ignore
End Try
Try
    Var3 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test3").InnerText
Catch ex As Exception
     'ignore
End Try
```

So if you have a lot of these you would be better wrapping this in a function:

```
Public Shared Function GetNodeInnerText(node as XmlNode, nodeName As String) As String
    If node Is Nothing Then Return ""
    Dim singleNode = node.SelectSingleValue(nodeName)
    If singleNode Is Nothing Then Return ""
    Return singleNode.InnerText
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, 

Yes this works, thank you, yet I've like 50+ nodes to analyze, wish there was another way.

Comment: Alright, did the last option you gave me and working as a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nuget package [Monads.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Monads/). to get monad "Maybe".
Use it:

```
var1 = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("Test1").With(Function(c) c.InnerText)
```

it inside check that node is not null and if it is not, return InnerText, in another case return null.